# Net Liquidity vs. Maintenance Margin margin call approximation

Tags: margin, margin-call

I have been trying to understand margin calls properly, but since my margin was always insignificant I never really did. Now that my stocks dropped significantly I feel like I may be close to a margin call.

Is it correct to say, that generally speaking total liquidation value (what is left if I sell all my stocks and pay back my margin loan) should be above maintenance margin? Or should initial margin never go below maintenance margin? I know this is not an exact solution, but generally speaking.

And another question if I sell part of my stocks, so my cash balance goes from -60k to -30k would that significantly derisk the whole thing or would it stay the same, after all Im just moving money from one asset to another?

Screenshot for reference:
[image]

Also, since some stocks seem to have different margin requirements, how do I find out what my situation is exactly? It seems to be no easy task.

What is also confusing is, that maintenance margin seems to be the intraday 25% instead of the overnight 50% relevant for investors like me. Or am I wrong?

**Currently I think the following:**

Available funds means I can spend this money without depositing new funds. Meaning as long as this value is positive I won't be called. And this is also the value by which my net value would need to decrease before I get called.
Available funds + initial margin = net liquidation value. So I need to watch out for initial margin and not let net liquidity get too close to it. However I am unsure about the whole "overnight" thing.

Comment: maybe ask your broker?

Comment: I did but they weren’t terribly helpful.